# How to figure out when SIP call is started

Tags: sip, sip-server

I'm writing simple SIP-proxy application which stands between Astreisk and SIP client (any softphone). The purpose of the application is to calculate the duration of the call.

Below is example of regular flow:

1. Client sends INVITE to SIP-Proxy, SIP-Proxy resends INVITE to Asterisk
2. Asterisk answers with 200 OK, SIP-Proxy resends 200 OK to client.
3. Client answers with ACK, SIP-Proxy resends ACK to Asterisk
4. Whenever one of the parties sends BYE, conversation should be finished.

On step 2 I assumes that call is started (e.g. rtp media flow is started). Then I wait for BYE message to calculate duration of the call. However I noticed that some clients never goes to step 3 and 4. No call end notification received from any parties after step 2. And duration of such call is infinitely.

What is the best way to find out start/stop time of the SIP call without sniffing RTP flow ?  Should I wait for step 3 to mark the start of the call ? What if client omit ACK or what if UDP datagram with ACK is missed in the network ?

For now I used to think there is no reliable way to figure out that SIP call is started. Maybe I should use Astrisk channels API instead to track active calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to generate a RE-INVITE to test the existence of the Session. Dont have to negotiate a timer or anything. Just using re-invite could help. Reuse the SDP to ensure that no media changes happen. But then your application is moving out of being a Proxy in the path of the call to being a application server.

Also the duration can only be capped to nearest interval for this re-invite request and not necessarily the exact time the call was released.

Comment: Finally after debugig I managed to figure out that it happens when BYE packets was lost due retransmission. For example if we have 10 seconds network spike, bye packet will be lost. If I do re-invite very 1-2 minute will it help to check whether call is still alive ?

Comment: yep, periodic pinging with Re-INvite should help you determine the presence of the call on the remote-server. Either it may not respond at all or reply with a 481 / 408. In either case you could possibly tear down the call.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be at SIP level, because your proxy does not add itself into the message path using a **Route** header. This process is called **Record Routing**. If doing so, all subsequent requests in your dialog will also traverse it (ACKs and BYEs included).

You should not reinvent the wheel by writing a SIP proxy. For example, you could use a open-source, flexible, powerful and completely customizable SIP Proxy in order to build any possible scenario you could think of: [OpenSIPS](http://opensips.org/)!